# bootstrap how to display the selected image( from img src=" ") in the same window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to show the selected image in the same window.i have 2 forms. the second form has the images. i need to show the selected image in my first div calss. since am new to bootstrap i dont know how to do it. can anyone help me to solve this. thank you.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">         
              <form  method="POST" action="information.php">
                 <div class="">
                     <p> Your Book TCS </p>
                 </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">

      // I NEED TO SHOW THE IMAGE HERE

            </div>
    </div>


<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="col-sm-3"> </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="form2"> 
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="column">
    <img src="img/image.png" class="rounded float-left" alt="Cinque Terre">

                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP wasn't specific about ***how*** the image gets there, like does a user need to click a button or does this happen at loading? This demo has 9 thumbnails that when clicked, a larger image of said thumbnail is displayed.

### Demo

```js
var view = document.getElementById('view');
var list = document.getElementById('list');

list.addEventListener('click', reveal, false);

function reveal(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.cyurrentTarget) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    var src = tgt.src;
    view.querySelector('img').src = src;
  }
}
```

```css
#list {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#view img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<div class="col-sm-12">

  <form method="POST" action="information.php">
    <div class="">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div id='view' class="col-sm-12">
    <img src='' width='45%' height='auto'>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="form2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column col-12">
      <ul id='list'>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=1'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0ff/000?text=2'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/83d800/000?text=3'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f7a/000?text=4'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/fc0/000?text=5'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f00/fff?text=6'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/48c/fff?text=7'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/0b2/fff?text=8'></li>
        <li><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/255/fff?text=9'></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i show one of the image when page loads first time?

Comment: Indeed you can, sir. I left the `src` blank in the demo, so all you need to do is add that `src` to whatever `img` you want.